# how do you use onChange property on react formik radio field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am looking to use onchange function whenever i click on different radio button. But whenever i try to do this, the default behaviour of formik is lost.

```
const initialValues = {
hasParent:"no"
}

const handleParentRadioChange = (val) => {
    if (val === 'yes') {
      alert('true');
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  };
const submitData = (value) =>{
  console.log(value); 
}


<Formik
   initialValues={initial}
   onSubmit={submitData}
  >
    <Field
    onChange={() => handleParentRadioChange('yes')}
    type="radio"
    name="hasParent"
    value="yes"
    />
    Yes
 <Field
    onChange={() => handleParentRadioChange('no')}
    type="radio"
    name="hasParent"
    value="no"
    />
    No
</Formik>
```

How do I perform onChange on formik field without the default formik property being lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onChange property does not work in formik radio...you can achieve same thing using through onClick. https://formik.org/docs/examples/radio-group

Answer (score 0):

Same as the docs but with out the use of the formik Feild component

```
   <div>
  <Formik
    initialValues={{
      picked: '',
    }}
    onSubmit={async (values) => {
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }}
  >
    {({ values, handleChange, handleBlur }) => (
      <Form>
        <div id="my-radio-group">Picked</div>
        <div role="group" aria-labelledby="my-radio-group">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="picked"
              value="One"
              checked={values.picked === 'One'}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            One
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="picked"
              value="Two"
              checked={values.picked === 'Two'}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
            Two
          </label>
          <div>Picked: {values.picked}</div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    )}
  </Formik>
</div>
```